# AJAX for upvote/downvote

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement upvote/downvote for forum posts. I have some Jquery code written up and it's working when you click the up-arrow or the down-arrow. But there are two issues:

1. There is an up arrow like I mentioned that I'm using from bootstrap and then to the right of the arrows I have a counter for how many times each post was upvoted and downvoted. There is some default spacing, that I guess comes from bootstrap. When I click the button, the arrow and the corresponding counter number lose their spacing. But go back to normal when I refresh the page.
2. When a user clicks the up arrow, the arrow and counter turn green. And when a user clicks the down arrow, the down arrow and counter turn red (only to the current user). When I refresh or go back to the page, the color disappears and goes back to normal. How can I get the colors of the voted posts to stay for the current user?

**_forum_post.html.erb**

```
<div class="pull-left vote-links">         
    <%= link_to like_forum_forum_thread_forum_post_path(@forum, @forum_thread, forum_post), class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top upvoteButton', method: :put do %>
    <%= forum_post.get_upvotes.size %>      
    <% end %><br />

    <%= link_to dislike_forum_forum_thread_forum_post_path(@forum, @forum_thread, forum_post), class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom downvoteButton' , method: :put do %>
    <%= forum_post.get_downvotes.size %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**forum_posts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.vote-links').on('click', 'a', function(e) {  
 e.preventDefault();   
  var currentTarget = $(e.currentTarget); 
  var voteLinksDiv = currentTarget.parents('.vote-links');

   if (currentTarget.is('.upvoteButton')) {
    currentTarget.css({color: 'green'});          
    voteLinksDiv.find('.downvoteButton').css({color: '#333'});      
   }

   else {
    currentTarget.css({color: 'red'});        
    voteLinksDiv.find('.upvoteButton').css({color: '#333'});
   }        

  $.ajax({
    url: currentTarget.attr('href'),
    type: 'PUT',        
  data: { format: 'json' },
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {        
    voteLinksDiv.find('a.upvoteButton').text(xhr.responseJSON.upvote);
    voteLinksDiv.find('a.downvoteButton').text(xhr.responseJSON.downvote);
  }
  });
 return false;
 });
});
```

**forum_posts_controller.rb**

```
def upvote  

@forum_post.upvote_by current_user

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.json { render :json => { downvote: @forum_post.get_downvotes.size, upvote: @forum_post.get_upvotes.size  } }
  format.js
 end
end

def downvote
 @forum_post.downvote_by current_user

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.json { render :json => { downvote: @forum_post.get_downvotes.size, upvote: @forum_post.get_upvotes.size  } }
  format.js
 end
end
```